# How to include references used in Supplementary material to main text

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

According to the guide of APS, I have to include the additional references in the supplementary material should be included in the main text. 
In other words, I need to put references used in one file to another file. 
However, I have no idea how it can be possible in latex.
What is the best way to achieve this goal in latex.

EDIT:  I want to elaborate my problem. First, there is a main.tex that is associated to one bib file(let's say ref.bib). And there is another latex file(say supp.tex) that has some references in it. However, for some reason, I have to include those references to main.pdf  and there should be no references in supp.pdf. Therefore, ref.bib contains all the information about the references of supp.tex. Then what should I do next?

Comment: I'm not convinced I understand the question, but are you looking for something like a 'Further Reading' section?

Comment: @SeanAllred I've just elaborated my question. If there is a solution, please help me.

Comment: @SeanAllred it is not a Further Reading section. The two references from two tex files should be merged and included to the first pdf file.

Comment: I would bet there is a way to do this with a wizard-like combination of `pdfpages` and `\include`s, but I don't know how to go about it, either.  Hopefully someone will know a solution, but it would *really* help you to put up a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that someone can recreate your situation easily.